# AWS Cloud Formation S3 Bucket Name already exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a bucket with the following cloud formation template:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "LoggingBucket": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "Properties": {
        "BucketName": {
          "Fn::Join": [
            "/",
            [
              {
                "Ref": "AWS::Region"
              },
              {
                "Ref": "Environment"
              },
              "backend-logs"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, it gives the following error when creating a stack:

```
us-east-1/development/backend-logs already exists
```

It seems like the error is bit misleading - if I change the the `/` to `.`, it works.

I also checked against the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) and although it seems like `/` is an invalid character, it seems like the `/` perhaps conflicts with their own internal naming schema or something.

Am I correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not with slash it is with the bucket name.

When you use `us-east-1/development/backend-logs` It tries to create a bucket name "development" with a subfolder "backend-logs" and "development" is a very common name and already taken by some one and S3 buckets follow universal naming convention thats why that error as that name is not available.

When you use `us-east-1/development.backend-logs` it creates bucket by name "development.backend-logs" which is available and thats why the bucket gets created.

Comment: Ah..How can I forget that names must be unique!! Thanks a mil!